# TikZ arrows problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, arrows

I was trying to put arrows on some lines using the TikZ package and the information of this website https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.17, where it's using the command [>=Stealth] to abbreviate the code, but for some reason it's not working on my Overleaf document. I have identified the problem, it seems like the command \usepackage[spanish]{babel} is messing with the arrows somehow, but I don't know why.

Here's the code

```latex
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth][scale=3]
    \draw [->] (-0.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw [->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,1.5);
    \draw [<<-,very thick] (0.3,0.3) -- (1.2,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the command \usepackage[spanish]{babel} muted so it doesn't mess with the diagram, which is below.[image]

Comment: Add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to the preamble of your document (after `\usepackage{tikz}`), and move `\usetikzlibrary{intersections} \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` **before** `\begin{document}`.

Comment: It works, thank you, but do I have to put the commands always before \begin{document} like now? and is there a way to put the [spanish] option like before?

Comment: Yes, you have to load the libraries before `\begin{document}`. And I am not sure if `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` has separate options for different languages. Rather, I think that this library works for all languages alike.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much :)